# Can not access to static methods in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a problem when trying to access a static method of some class.
Here is the code and the error message:

```
(ns demo.app
  (:import 
     [java.nio.file Paths]
     [java.util List])

=> (Paths/get "a" "B" "c")
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method: get, compiling:(*cider-repl clj-demo*:68:16) 

=> (java.nio.file.Paths/get ".")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.net.URI  clj-demo.ch08/eval11327 (form-init3786136217280477578.clj:76)

=> (java.nio.file.Paths/get "." "finally.txt")
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;  clj-demo.ch08/eval11329 (form-init3786136217280477578.clj:78)
```

The java doc follows:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)

I've found on https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop , it writes:

> (Classname/staticMethod args*)

I also tried these:

```
=> (System/getProperty "java.vm.version")
"25.102-b14"

=> (clojure-version)
"1.8.0"
```

No problem. So:

Why does `Paths/get` not work in REPL?

Why does `java.nio.file.Paths/get` not work, either?

Why does `Paths/get` and `java.nio.file.Paths/get` get different error messages?

I've also tried

```
(List/of 0) ;; => [0]
(List/of 1 2 3) ;; => Method
   java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
   must be InterfaceMethodref constant
(List/of (Integer. 1)) ;; =>  Method java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List; must
   be InterfaceMethodref constant
(List/of "s") ;; =>    Method java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List; must
   be InterfaceMethodref constant
```

Comment: Thanks to Clojure and JAVA nio package,
I've changed to this, and it works:
`(ns demo.app
  (:import [java.nio.file Files Paths]))
(Files/readAllBytes (Paths/get "." (into-array ["alice.txt"])))` , but still can not answer the first question.

Comment: I also got these(java 10)  
`(List/of 0) ;; => [0]
(List/of 1 2 3) ;; => Method
   java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List;
   must be InterfaceMethodref constant
(List/of (Integer. 1)) ;; =>  Method java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List; must
   be InterfaceMethodref constant
(List/of "s") ;; =>    Method java.util.List.of(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/List; must
   be InterfaceMethodref constant`

Comment: @cmal This is a bug in Clojure: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-2284

Comment: OK. Thank you for this information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Paths.get(String, String...)` takes two arguments - a string and an array of strings. Java creates the array automatically for you, but in clojure you need to construct the array yourself e.g.

```
(Paths/get "a" (into-array String ["b" "c"]))
```

Calling

```
(java.nio.file.Paths/get ".")
```

fails because the only [overload of `get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) which takes a single argument requires it to be a `URI` not a `String`.